# Meteor mobile: How to use WebAppLocalServer.localFileSystemUrl() documentation or example?

Tags: cordova, meteor

The Meteor mobile guide has a section on 
[accessing local files](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#accessing-local-files):

> The file serving mechanism used in Meteor allows for local file access through URLs of the form http://localhost:/local-filesystem/) however. You can construct these file system URLs manually, or use **WebAppLocalServer.localFileSystemUrl()** to convert file:// URLs.

However I cannot find any documentation, code, or examples on how to use `WebAppLocalServer.localFileSystemUrl()`

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it on GitHub:

cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.WebAppLocalServer

The webapp plugin is an integral part of meteor-cordova code, and is installed when you run 'meteor create' so you don't have to do an import, you can just use it as it is with calls like this:

WebAppLocalServer.localFileSystemUrl(fileUrl)

`fileUrl` is expected to begin with `file://`, if it doesn't, the method just returns the fileUrl as it is.